# Node - CSS File not being picked on one path but picked on other

Tags: css, node.js

I have a html file, being generated by a third party library that I need to serve on a route in a node server.

The html file and the related css files are generated in a folder called public having the following structure.

```
src -|
     | - public -|
     |           | - css -|
     |           |        | - css-file.css
     |           | - index.html
     | - server.js
```

The html file refers to the css file as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css-file.css" />
```

I cannot change this, as the `index.html` and the related `css` file is being generated by a third party library.

In the `server.js` file, I have the following code

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));

app.get('/path/one',(req, res) => {
   res.set({'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html'))
}

app.get('/pathTwo', (req, res) => {
   res.set({'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html'))   
}
```

The css file gets picked up on `/pathTwo`, but does not get picked up on `/path/one`. I am not able to figure out why.

**Edit**
One thing that I notice from the logs

- For `/path/one`, node is looking for the file at the location `/path/css/css-file.css` and not at `/css/css-file.css`

From express docs for `express.static`

***The function determines the file to serve by combining req.url with the provided root directory.***

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to send the html as a file instead of accessing it directly? Just because it's in the the public folder already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***WORKAROUND***

Found a workaround for this.

Looking at the logs and the network calls, for the css, the following call is being made for fetching the css file

```
GET /path/css/css-file.css
```

This call fails with a 404, resulting in the css not being used for the html.

I added a new route in the server, as below

```
app.get(`path/css/:fileName`, (req, res) => {
   const fileName = req.params.fileName;
   const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `./public/css/${fileName}`);
   res.set({'Content-Type', 'test/css'})
   res.sendFile(filePath);
}
```

This returns the CSS file from the desired path, and ultimately being used by the HTML file.

This seems to be just a workaround, and not a solution from within `express.static`.

Hope that someone would provide a solution here.

Thanks in advance!!